# Node.Js wierd error

Tags: node.js

So I run my app and at one point I get this error after creating a deposite.

```
[2017-10-26 20:44:39.692] [DEBUG] [default] - Tradeoffer #2624930742 (sent - joinJackpot) with code : tPHJsg has been created by steamid: 76561198114317007
(node:13756) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually, you can see this error when you have the wrong signature of your method. Could you show us your code?

Comment: thats... just a notice. you're calling an asynchronous function without giving it a callback. Maybe on purpose, maybe by accident. but doing so is deprecated. https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0013_fs_asynchronous_function_without_callback

Comment: If any of you @Alex have discord or skype we can talk because this is a code that I can't share in public and has to remain private.

Comment: @Kevin If you want to help we can go talk on slype or other program because the code can't be share in public.

Comment: yeah, how about no. I don't need to see your entire codebase anyway, or any of it really. You need to look through it for any usage of `fs` that is async without a callback. It very well could be a npm module you have installed too.

Comment: @KevinB what does a callback should look like?

Comment: I have a total of 16 fs in my main app that I lunch.

Comment: it will look something like fs.dosomething() with no function in the ()

Comment: All my fs have a function between the () @KevinB

Comment: then maybe it's somthing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the error was cause by the OS and not the actual script. So I switch from Ubuntu 17 to Debian 8